# How do I calculate this sampling error?

Tags: probability, standard-deviation, sampling, standard-error

If I sample individual integer values $0$ to $100$ from a distribution $100000$ times and record the counts for all integer values between $0$ and $100$, how do I calculate the $95$% error bars for the probability of my next sample being equal to a certain value?
If I sample $100000$ times again, the probabilities I calculate will likely be different to my initial calculations; how do I account for this?

Comment: Clarification: are all values $0$ to $100$ the only ones possible?  And what size is each sample?  Are you taking $100,000$ individual values of the random variable?  Or are you taking many values to get a sample mean, and taking sample means $100,000$ times?

Comment: Yes the values recorded are only between 0 and 100. The same sizes vary from 10000 to 1 depending on the value. Yes, 100000 individual values were sampled from an unknown distribution. Then dividing the number of times a value is recorded divided by 100000 is how I calculated probability

Comment: Also, is the variable discrete or continuous?  And how much confidence do you want in your estimate for the next sample?  $90$%?  $95$%?

Comment: It is discrete, the values are only integers. and 95% confidence

Comment: Thank you. I have edited your question to reflect the clarifications; please make changes if I have introduced any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you pick the value $43$.  You got that value a certain number of times $x$ in $100000$ draws, for a proportion or probability $p = \frac{x}{100000}$. If you are only interested in the value $43$, we can essentially divide the whole situation into a binary choice: $43$ or not $43$.

If I read your question right, you are asking for the error in that proportion.  The standard error of a sample proportion is $\sqrt{\frac{pq}{n}}$ where $q = 1-p$.  Your sample size is large, and assuming $x$ is also large, then you can approximate the distribution of probability of getting $43$ as a normal distribution.  So your $95$% confidence interval would be $\frac{x}{100000} \pm 1.96 \sqrt{\frac{pq}{100000}}$

Comment: Is this also valid when x is small? for example, for the value that only had a single recording would this be valid?

Comment: I'm not certain about the case $x = 1.$ I do know the special case $x=0$ is handled with the "rule of 3", namely, the $95$% CI for the proportion in that case is approximately $[0,3/n]$.

Comment: In most textbooks on elementary statistics that I've read, one of the requirements to develop a confidence interval of this type is that we've observed at least ten "successes" and ten "failures" among our observed data. So if we observe $x=1$ successes and $100,000−x=99,999$ failures, it wouldn't be appropriate to develop this CI.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Indeed.  Yet we still want to be able to make one.  Apparently it hasn't yet been determined exactly how to do that, hence the "rule of $3$" I mentioned.  I had to hunt around a while even to find that much; book after book simply said "it has to be big enough" without mentioning what to do instead when it wasn't.

Comment: I would be curious to see how this case is handled, because I've never seen a confidence interval developed for a population proportion when the observed number of successes is so small. I've even seen textbooks write "consult a statistician" in this scenario.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I found something! In William Navidi's textbook *Elementary Statistics*, he suggests using the adjusted confidence interval $$\tilde{p}\pm z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{\tilde{p}(1-\tilde{p})}{n+4}}$$ when the observed number of success or the observed number of failures is less than $10$. Here, $\tilde{p}=\frac{x+2}{n+4}$ is the "adjusted" observed sample proportion.

Comment: @MatthewPilling for this method, am I right to assume the z term would remain as 1.96?

Comment: @Hamzah yes, $z$ would remain $1.96$

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards